# Regenerate resolv.conf from dhclient.conf without releasing/renewing IP?

Tags: dns, dhcp, resolv.conf, dhclient, resolvconf

When I make changes to `dhclient.conf` such as [modifying the DNS search path](http://mutexlock.blogspot.com/2010/01/resetting-overwriting-etcresolvconf-in.html) (so that the changes don't get lost on reboot or DHCP renews), how do I regenerate `/etc/resolv.conf`? That page suggests `dhclient -r; dhclient` which releases the address, thus disrupting my connection and preventing me from reaching the host again. Is there another way of doing this? Thanks.

Comment: I don't use dhcp, but I do use the command 'resolvconf -u' to re-write resolv.conf when doing some VPN related tasks.

Comment: @ScottSalley I did try just issuing `resolvconf -u` but it doesn't incorporate the changes made to `dhclient.conf`.

Comment: Are the change you make specific to dhcp on your network, or are they more general? If they are more general, you could add them to /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base and then 'resolvconf -u' would do you some good.

Comment: @ScottSalley It's changes like the `supersede domain-name "...";` directive in the page I linked to, as an example. If I add them to `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` won't they just get overwritten on e.g. next reboot/renew?

Answer (score -1):

Just use your favorite editor to edit /etc/resolv.conf (or /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf if you are running Ubuntu 12.04 or later with resolvconf active).

After a reboot or an interface downup cycle, resolv.conf should be correctly regenerated so that you can reconnect. If that isn't the case then you have another problem.

Comment: That's actually the type of hack I do today in a one-off fashion (so far can handle `supersede domain-name` only), but since this is part of a general-purpose configuration management system, I was hoping for a more systematic way rather than writing/reproducing code to understand the various types of clauses in `dhclient.conf` and applying them to resolv.conf.